# Get Higher Precision from GGMAP

Tags: r

I have the following code.

```
library(ggmap)
x = geocode("641123",output='all')
x$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lat
```

shows 55.62943.

If i query

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=641123&sensor=false
```

The lat shown is 55.62942899999999.

I need higher precision, it there a way to get the missing decimal place ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's there, the printing is just clipping it. Use `format` among other things to see the entire value...

```
library(ggmap)
x = geocode("641123",output='all')
> format(x$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lat, digits=20)
[1] "55.629428999999988"
```